# How to convert Quicktime .MOV to Adobe filmstrip format?

Tags: video, quicktime, photoshop

Hi
Does anyone know of a way to convert Quicktime .MOV files to Adobe filmstrip format?
I'm trying to color correct video files in Photoshop, but don't own Adobe Premiere..

Comment: I am not familiar with Adobe filmstrip format, but I know that you can open Quicktime files in Photoshop Extended and you have timeline and a few animation controls if it helps. Might worth posting this on www.superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

That functionality was removed after CS3 ( import as filmstrip). You can however still edit / rotoscope video

Create a canvas the size of your video
go to layers >> Video Layers >> New Video Layer from file
Select your video

You can then apply your filters to that layer as needed to the video

note you can also do this within the timeline vs. layer manager